# How to prevent manually set url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I create one quiz app. In which students attend the question and click on the next button next question appears. now the **issue** is that the student is on the second question and the URL like "**`takeQuizStudent/149?page=2`**" and he manually changes URL to "**`takeQuizStudent/149?page=1`**". so it should not happen. Once clicks on the next question he can't go back to the **previous** question.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, there's no way to prevent the client (browser) from making a request with any URL they like. You'll have to take another approach, probably by maintaining the quiz *state* in the session.

Answer (score 3):

You should check request page number from `session` in your controller,for example

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{

  $value = $request->session()->get('pageNumber'); //2

  //$id = 1
  if($id < $value){
     return response("invalid request",504);
  }

  //else update pageNumber value and do continue

 // Via a request instance...
 $request->session()->put('pageNumber', '3');

 // Via the global helper...
 session(['pageNumber' => '3']);

     .....
}
```

**Determining If An Item Exists In The Session**

To determine if an item is present in the session, you may use the `has` method. The `has` method returns `true` if the item is present and is not `null`:

```
if ($request->session()->has('pageNumber')) {
    //
}
```

To determine if an item is present in the session, even if its value is `null`, you may use the `exists` method. The `exists` method returns `true` if the item is present:

```
if ($request->session()->exists('pageNumber')) {
    //
}
```